# Qt table view with row wrapping instead of scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have a question about Qt table view. I need a table with no horizontall scroll, but columns doesn't fit on the screen must located below. Like this:

[image]

Help?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `QTableView` or `QTableWidget` won't bend to do that. You will have to implement your own view, something like "flowview".